# Help with Table Performance & Nightly Maintenance Job

Tags: sql-server

I'm running into a strange issue where a table's (~14 mil records) performance is degraded at various periods of time. It appears to be one problematic query, however once I optimize the indexes and update statistics, the table's performance increases dramatically. I've added WITH (NO LOCK) to the problematic query. I also optimize the indexes recommended here - https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html through 8 steps of IndexOptimize (with fragmentation levels in increments of 10) and then I update statistics on all of the tables in our database.

Example: 80% - 90% fragmentation optimization

```
EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
    @FragmentationLow = NULL,
    @FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
    @FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
    @FragmentationLevel1 = 80,
    @FragmentationLevel2 = 90,
    @MaxDOP = 0,
    @SortinTempDB = 'Y',
    @LogToTable = 'Y'
```

Example of updating statistics:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable'PRINT ''?''; UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'
```

Does anyone see anything blatantly wrong with these steps? I wonder if our statistics are getting out of date and not automatically updating. I am stumped.

Comment: Are you running the ola scripts every night? What is the timing of the degraded performance?

Comment: Hello, yes I'm running this job nightly at 11:59 PM ET. The degraded performance occurs anytime between 10:00 AM - 1:00 PM. It's not quite a definitive time. Should I set "Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously" to true? The problematic table is written to very frequently by our application.

Comment: I was mostly asking to get the timeline, "Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously" is something that [should only be done if you have good reason,](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-update-stats-async-enabled/) I am not sure if you have that now.  I am assuming you have 'Auto Update Statistics" = True.

Comment: Got it. That is correct, "Auto Update Statistics" = True.

Comment: If you're in 2016 you may check the Query store, this will save some information about the query and you can see the different execution plans, if there's something strange you may "force" one specific plan.

Comment: I am on 2016. I'm a little weary about pinning a specific query because this data is changing frequently. However, I'll check it out. Thank you!

Comment: We ran this script - http://sqlworldwide.com/tsql-to-find-status-of-sql-server-statistics/ and confirmed that the degraded performance is a result of an index's statistics being updated. How do I make sure that index isn't updated?

Comment: I disabled auto update statistics for table by running "EXEC sp_autostats 'table_name', 'OFF' ". I'm running the Index Optimization & Update Statistics job tonight. I'll report back tomorrow.